# Form group issue Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am seeing the below error all the time:

```
formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
```

In HTML:

```html
<mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
<form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
```

I have this in my `.ts` file:

```js
firstFormGroup!: FormGroup;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to initialize the value for the form group.
In your component code add this

```
  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
     // add your form controls here 
    });
  }
```